# listen/notify using pg_notify(text,text)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Can I pass URL in `pg_notify()`?

My intent is to send data from one database to other database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass any string you like as second parameter to `pg_notify`, but notification does not work across databases.

Only users connected to the same database will receive the notification.

Comment: is it possible to pass data via url by using pg_notify  ?

Comment: The complete URL string is available to the recipient, so it can extract any information from it. This is true regardless if the string is an URL or not. The URL will never be treated as such; no HTTP requests are sent etc.

Comment: ((( p.code ) :: text  ||  ':'  :: text)  || ( g.code ) :: text )  AS country_code . I want to ask that what is the meaning of "::text" in postgresql.

Comment: It is a type cast to type `text`.